# Nest one content type in another to be able to add single fields

Tags: entities, commerce, nodes

I would like to have one content type "Basic" and then another content type "Premium" that has a few extra fields than the basic one. The idea is that I want my users to pay for premium publications (using [Commerce Node Checkout Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_node_checkout)) if they want to use those extra fields. Basic content will always be free.

It is very likely that I will need to make changes to the basic content type fields that I want to also be reflected in the permium content type. Is there a way to kind of "subtheme" the content type so that it reflects the basic one whenever changes are made but still carries a few extra fields that are independend of these changes?

Answer (score 2):

That's quite a cool question...

I think If I were doing it, I would have the basic form available to all standard users of a standard permissions role...

Then when a customer has paid for the privilege to use more advanced fields, I set up a rule to promote their role to an advanced user role after checkout.

You can then use a module like [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to determine which fields your basic users can edit, and which fields your advanced users can edit.

And, you only need one content type.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comments because I realized that there is a problem with this solution. When a user pays to create a node, he doesn't get promoted to a premium _user role_ (payment is per node). I would need 'Field Permissions per node', i.e., give the user premium rights for _that_ specific node only. But such a feature doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I see. Perhaps give the users permissions to only edit "own content", then the user can only edit the one node that is created for them on payment. 
Then, set up a rule that upgrades the users permissions to edit all of that nodes fields after purchase.
If it is through commerce, there are a set of rules for after checkout that you could use to upgrades a users role.